# Como solucionar o erro: String data, right truncated: 1406

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Olá, segue a minha dúvida:

---

Estou tentando salvar os dados do Checklist Protocolo, mas está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'item' at row 1

Como solucionar este problema?

**1. Segue a imagem do modal Checklist Protocolo:**
É o formulário responsável por receber os dados inseridos pelo usuário.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2. Segue a imagem do erro, ao tentar cadastrar os dados:** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**3. Método de cadastroChecklistProtocolo da classe ProjetoController.php**
Este método e responsável por cadastrar os dados do checklist protocolo no banco de dados.

```
   public function cadastroChecklistProtocolo(Request $request)

    {
        // Deletar a tabela de checklist_protocolo
       $checklistsProtocolos = ChecklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id', $request->projeto_id)->delete();

 $data = $request->all();
        $dataInsert = [];
            //Observe que eu tirei o push ($dataInsert[]) pois assim iria adicionar mais uma array no fim 
            $dataInsert = [
                'projeto_id' => $data['projeto_id'],
                'item' => $data ['item'],
                'modelo_id' => $data['modelo_id'],
                'item_descricao_id' => $data ['item_descricao_id'],
                'sim_nao' => $data ['sim_nao'],
                'nao_atende' => $data ['nao_atende'],
                'dt_validade' => $data ['dt_validade'],
                'pagina_documento' => $data ['pagina_documento'],
                'observacao' => $data ['observacao'],

            ];

            //dd($dataInsert);
           $dados =  ChecklistProtocolo::create($dataInsert); 

     $response= true;

        if($response)
        {
            return redirect()
                      ->route('projeto.edita', $request->projeto_id) 
                      ->with('success',"Sucesso ao atualizar os Checklists do Protocolo");
        }else
        {
            return redirect()
                      ->back()
                      ->with('error',"Erro ao atualizar o Checklists do Protocolo"); 
        } 
    }
```

**4. Código do Modal ChecklistProtocolo:**

```
  <!--Inicio do modal de Checklist do Projeto-->
<form id="checklistProtocolo" action="{{route('projeto.cadastroChecklistProtocolo')}}" method="POST">

                  {{ csrf_field() }}  
  <div class="modal fade modal-default" id="modalChecklist" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="examplePositionCenter"
                 role="dialog" tabindex="-1">

                <div class="modal-dialog2 modal-center">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Checklists do Protocolo</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                             <input type="hidden" id="projeto_id" name="projeto_id" value="{{$projeto->id}}">
                             <input type="hidden" id="modelo_id"  name="modelo_id" value="{{$modeloProtocolo[0]['id']}}">
                             <label class="control-label">Modelo</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="modeloProcesso" value="{{$modeloProtocolo[0]['modelo']}}" disabled> 

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-18">

                             <table id="checklistProtocolo" name="checklistProtocolo" class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive toggle-arrow-tiny" >
                                <caption></caption>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Item</th> 
                                            <th>Descrição</th>
                                            <th>Sim/Não</th>
                                            <th>Não Atende</th>
                                            <th>Data de Validade</th>
                                            <th>Página do Documento</th>
                                            <th><center>Observações</center> </th>
                                            <th class="text-center"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="bodyChecklists">

                            @foreach($checklistsProtocolos as $checklistProtocolo)

                                <tr>
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  id="item" name="item[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}"  size ="2"></td>
                                    <td>{{$checklistProtocolo->descricao_item}}</td>   
                                    <input type="hidden"          id="item_descricao_id"  name="item_descricao_id[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item_descricao_id}}">
                                    <td><input type="checkbox"    id="sim_nao"            name="sim_nao[]"    {{$checklistProtocolo->sim_nao == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
                                    <td><input type="checkbox"    id="nao_atende"         name="nao_atende[]" {{$checklistProtocolo->nao_atende == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
                                    <td><input type="date"        id="dt_validade"        name="dt_validade[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->dt_validade}}"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"        id="pagina_documento"   name="pagina_documento[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->pagina_documento}}" size ="1"></td>
                                    <td><input type="text"        id="observacao"         name="observacao[]" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->observacao}}" size ="1" style="width: 300px; height: 60px"></td>
                                </tr>

                            @endforeach 

                               </tbody>
                        </table>



                        </div>

                        </div><!--Fim do modal-body-->

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <center>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  aria-hidden="true" style="width: 300px; height: 40px" > Salvar</button>

                        </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>  
  <!--Fim do modal do Checklist do Projeto-->
```

**5. Código do modelo ChecklistProtocolo.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use DB;
use SoftDeletes;

class ChecklistProtocolo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "checklist_protocolo";

    protected $primaryKey =  ['projeto_id', 'modelo_id','itens_descricao_id'];

    public $incrementing = false;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected  $fillable  = ['projeto_id', 'modelo_id','item','itens_descricao_id','sim_nao', 'nao_atende','dt_validade','pagina_documento','observacao'];

    protected $casts = [ 'item' => 'array', 'item_descricao_id'=> 'array','sim_nao' => 'array', 'dt_validade'=> 'array', 
    'pagina_documento'=> 'array', 'observacao'=> 'array', 'nao_atende'=> 'array'];

    /* 
    public function checklistProtocolo()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(ChecklistProtocolo::class, 'projeto_id','modelo_id', 'itens_descricao_id');
    } */

    //Este método salva os dados do Checklist do Protocolo
    public function salvar(ChecklistProtocolo $checklistProtocolo) : Array
    {
       $checklistProtocolo = $this->save();

         if($checklistProtocolo){

            return[
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'Sucesso ao cadastrar'
            ];   
        }
        else{

            return[
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Falha ao cadastrar'
            ]; 
        }
    }


    //Este método remove os dados do Checklist do Protocolo
  public function deletar(checklistProtocolo $checklistProtocolo) : Array
  {
      $checklistProtocolo =  $this->delete();
      if($checklistProtocolo){

          return[
              'success' => true,
              'message' => 'Sucesso ao excluir'
          ];   
      }
      else{

          return[
              'success' => false,
              'message' => 'Falha ao excluir'
          ]; 
      }
  }


//Este método atualiza os dados do  Checklist do Protocolo
public function alterar(checklistProtocolo $checklistProtocolo) : Array
{
  $checklistProtocolo = $this->save();
    if($checklistProtocolo){
        return[
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Sucesso ao atualizar'
        ];   
    }
    else{
        return[
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Falha ao atualizar'
        ]; 
    }
}


}
```

**6. Debug da variável "$request->all();"**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

 **7. Modelo ER"**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**8. Descrição da tabela do banco de dados**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seu `modelo_id` está diretamente dentro do `$request->all()` mas você tenta acessar ele dentro do loop

Comment: O correto seria `'projeto_id' => $data['projeto_id']` e o loop deveria ser feito apenas nos campos onde existe array: Item, item_descricao_id, sim_nao etc...

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta @edsonalves. Eu testei da forma que vc falou, mas ocorreu o seguinte erro: Illegal string offset 'item'.

Comment: É que o `item` também está no nivel 0 da array... Com "fazer o loop nos que são arrays" eu quis dizer algo como:  `foreach ($data['item'] as $items) {` e percorrer os valores dele... Mas vc não precisa fazer um loop direto em `$data` basta pegar os valores diretamente

Comment: Segue o método:  public function cadastroChecklistProtocolo(Request $request){
$data = $request->all();$dataInsert = []; $dataInsert['projeto_id'] =  $data['projeto_id']; $dataInsert['modelo_id'] =  $data['modelo_id'];

Comment: foreach ($data as $dataForm) {$dataInsert[] = ['item' => $dataForm['item'], 'item_descricao_id' => $dataForm['item_descricao_id'],'sim_nao' => $dataForm['sim_nao'],  'dt_validade' => $dataForm['dt_validade'],  'pagina_documento' => $dataForm['pagina_documento'],  'observacao' => $dataForm['observacao'], 'nao_atende' => $dataForm['nao_atende'],];

Comment: $dados =  ChecklistProtocolo::create($dataInsert);$dados->save(); }}

Comment: Atualiza sua pergunta com estes dados, não é legal colocar trechos tão grandes nos comentários

Comment: Olá @edson alves. A pergunta foi atualizada. Gostaria que você me demonstrasse um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme meu comentário, não é necessário realizar um loop nos dados do `$data` basta acessar diretamente:

Obs: Se eu Model não estiver preparado para aceitar arrays esta linha `$dados =  ChecklistProtocolo::create($dataInsert);` resultará em erro, já que `dataInsert` é um array de 2 níveis.

```
       $data = $request->all();
        $dataInsert = [];
            //Observe que eu tirei o push ($dataInsert[]) pois assim iria adicionar mais uma array no fim 
            $dataInsert = [
                'projeto_id' => $data['projeto_id'],
                'modelo_id' => $data['modelo_id'],
                'item' => $data ['item'],
                'item_descricao_id' => $data ['item_descricao_id'],
                'sim_nao' => $data ['sim_nao'],
                'dt_validade' => $data ['dt_validade'],
                'pagina_documento' => $data ['pagina_documento'],
                'observacao' => $data ['observacao'],
                'nao_atende' => $data ['nao_atende'],
            ];
           $dados =  ChecklistProtocolo::create($dataInsert);
           $dados->save();
```

**Update**

O erro

> SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for
>   column 'item' at row 1
>   Acontece pois sua coluna item (e outras) não tem espaço suficiente para salvar o dado, sendo apenas 10 caracteres.

Ao usar o `cast`, seu array será convertido em string para ser salvo, o que gera uma string bem maior que 10 caracteres.

Comment: Olá, @edson. Eu testei a sua solução, mas ocorreu o seguinte erro: Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `checklist_protocolo` (`projeto_id`, `item`, `modelo_id`, `sim_nao`, `nao_atende`, `dt_validade`, `pagina_documento`, `observacao`) values (12, 0, 7, on, on, 2018-11-28, 1, tetes))

Comment: Como eu disse, "Se eu Model não estiver preparado para aceitar arrays esta linha $dados =  ChecklistProtocolo::create($dataInsert); resultará em erro, já que dataInsert é um array de 2 níveis.", você está tentando inserir um array no banco, você pode adicionar uma mutator no seu model para cada valor com array, exemplo `protected $casts = [
        'item' => 'array',
    ];`

Comment: Ficaria: `$casts = [ 'item' => 'array', 'item_descricao_id'=> 'array' [...]];` fazendo isto para cada um dos valores que são array... Existem outras formas de fazer, por exemplo separando em tabelas, mas assim acho que vai ser mais fácil

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: Oi @edson alves. Eu inseri a variável $cast no modelo. Mas, ao salvar os dados ocorreu o seguinte erro: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'item' at row 1.

Comment: A dúvida foi atualizada.

Comment: Parece que sua coluna não tem espaço suficiente para aceitar a string. Qual o tipo dela e o tamanho? Adiciona sua migration na pergunta.

Comment: A descrição da tabela foi inserida na dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Solução para o projeto em questão foi criar uma variável ($cont) para contar linha de cada array dentro do loop de repetição que será refletido na View.

Referência:
[Salvar itens de um formulário checklist no banco - Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382561/salvar-itens-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio-checklist-no-banco-laravel)

Segue código:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($dt_validade); $i++){

                   $dataInsert = array(
                         'sim_nao' => $sim_nao[$cont],                   
                         'dt_validade'=> $dt_validade[$cont], 
                         'pagina_documento' =>$pagina_documento[$cont], 
                         'observacao' =>$observacao[$cont]);           

                         $checklistsProtocolos = checklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id', $projeto_id)
                         ->whereIn('item_descricao_id', (array)$item_descricao_id[$cont])  //atualiza linha por linha do array
                         ->update($dataInsert);
                         $cont++; //atualiza linha por linha do array
                  }
```