# Dúvida: Percorrer um array multidimensional Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5, array-multidimensional

Como otimizar percorrer dados do array multidimensional Laravel no Controller e o resultado ser refletido na View.

Exemplo:

```js
[{"item":"0","item_descricao_id":5,"sim_nao":null,"dt_validade":null,"pagina_documento":null,"observacao":null},
{"item":"1","item_descricao_id":6,"sim_nao":null,"dt_validade":null,"pagina_documento":null,"observacao":null},
{"item":"2","item_descricao_id":7,"sim_nao":null,"dt_validade":null,"pagina_documento":null,"observacao":null},
{"item":"3","item_descricao_id":8,"sim_nao":null,"dt_validade":null,"pagina_documento":null,"observacao":null},
{"item":"4","item_descricao_id":9,"sim_nao":null,"dt_validade":null,"pagina_documento":null,"observacao":null}]
```

Utilizando a função For no Controller o resultado de impressão é uma linha de array:

Código:

```html
      for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($item); $i++){
           $dataInsert = array( 
                       'item' => $item[$i], 
                       'item_descricao_id' => $item_descricao_id[$i], 
                       'sim_nao' => $sim_nao[$i], 
                       'dt_validade'=> $dt_validade[$i],
                       'pagina_documento' =>$pagina_documento[$i], 
                       'observacao' =>$observacao[$i]);
                     }
```

Resultado dessa função:

```js
{"item":"0","item_descricao_id":"5","sim_nao":null,"dt_validade":null,"pagina_documento":null,"observacao":null}
```

Neste caso existe alguma biblioteca do PHP que percorra as linhas dos array de arrays?

Comment: Parece que você quer trabalhar com collections, dê uma lida em [Collections: Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods)

Comment: @ErlonCharles Vou ler a documentação indicada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução aplicada foi criar uma variável ($cont) para contar linha de cada array dentro do loop de repetição que será refletido na View.

Referência:
[Salvar itens de um formulário checklist no banco - Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382561/salvar-itens-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio-checklist-no-banco-laravel)

Segue código:

```js
 $cont = 0; //contador de linhas para os arrays

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($item); $i++){
   $dataInsert = array( 
                 'item' => $item[$cont], 
                 'item_descricao_id' => $item_descricao_id[$cont], 
                 'sim_nao' => $sim_nao[$cont], 
                 'dt_validade'=> $dt_validade[$cont],
                 'pagina_documento' =>$pagina_documento[$cont], 
                 'observacao' =>$observacao[$cont]);      
            $cont++; 
         }
```

Comment: Nesse caso não poderia usar o sizeof($item) ou até mesmo o $i ?

Comment: @Darlei Fernando Zillmer Nessa situação foi erro na edição do código para a resposta. Utilizei o count neste caso. E como era necessário percorrer os outros array em um único formulário fez necessário mais uma variável para percorrer o array.